# How to make union all SQL-SQLite query by case statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I am confused while joining two tables with mulitple columns.
I want to find the players IDs from each group who got the maximum score. For example, player 45, 30, and 65 are in group 1 and 45 is the winner with maximum score.

Please help...

Here is table "players"

```
player_id | group_id
  -----------+----------
   20        | 2
   30        | 1
   40        | 3
   45        | 1
   50        | 2
   65        | 1
```

Table "matches"

```
match_id | first_player | second_player | first_score | second_score
 1          | 30           | 45            | 10          | 12
   2        | 20           | 50            | 5           | 5
   13       | 65           | 45            | 10          | 10
   5        | 30           | 65            | 3           | 15
   42       | 45           | 65            | 8           | 4
```

Expected Output:

```
group_id | winner_id
  ----------+-----------
   1        | 45
   2        | 20
   3        | 40
```

I tried:

```
select distinct gid, (case where...) as winner_id
from
(select a.first_player, a.second_player, a.first_score as fs, 
a.second_score as ss , p.group_id as gid
from
mathches as a
join players as p 
on p.player_id IN (a.first_player,a.second_player))
group by gid
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Should this work on MySQL, on SQLite, or in both worlds?

Comment: I am stuck at case how to choose between two column. I am working on SQLite. I am not sure we have different query in mysql.

Comment: For the sample data you posted there is no row in matches for player=40, so this player will not be in the results.

Comment: He did not participate in the current matches and He is alone in the group. He considered as winner itself. Is it possible somehow to bring him also by join case. But I really appreciate your response. :) I will learn alot from your queries.

Comment: If there are more than 1 players in a group that did not participate in any matches then 1 should be picked randomly?

Comment: See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must get the total score of each player and then join to `players`.
Then use FIRST_VALUE() window function to get the top player of each group:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.group_id, 
       FIRST_VALUE(p.player_id) OVER (PARTITION BY p.group_id ORDER BY m.score DESC) winner_id
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT player, SUM(score) score
  FROM (
    SELECT match_id, first_player player, first_score score FROM matches
    UNION ALL
    SELECT match_id, second_player, second_score FROM matches
  ) t
  GROUP BY player
) m ON m.player = p.player_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1d2f9ff54926652fece0e78664d4cd30).